# Why is the "Size" property of a control set by the designer when the control is docked to its parent in C# Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, size, dock

Consider a `TabelLayoutPanel`. I add it to `Form1` using the Visual Studio designer and set the `Dock` property to to `Fill`. Even though I have set the size using the `Dock` property,  the `Size` property is also set in `Form1.Designer.cs`

```
this.tableLayoutPanel.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.tableLayoutPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1000, 800);
```

Why is that? Why is the designer adding this line? Isn't the `Dock` property enough? Based on that, if I dynamically create this `TableLayoutPanel`, should I set both the `Dock` and the `Size`?

Comment: You don't need to set the `Size`. Setting `Dock` is enough.

Comment: @RezaAghaei - then why VS is adding it automatically?

Comment: come on now, stop looking behind the curtain, it's the Wizard we came to see not the old man

Comment: You need to reason through what should happen when you set the Dock property back to None in your code.  A logical answer would be: "well, it should then use the Size as set in the designer".  Right, it will.

Comment: I would say it's Initial size and it will remain when you remove docking style.

Comment: **What is serialized size?** Serialized size is not initial size, it's the size which you see in the designer the last time the size of control is set based on its dock state and based on its parent size. For example if you have a docked panel in form, each time you change the size of form, the size of panel will change too. So, the size will change based on dock property and parent size.  **What about changing size of panel at run-time by code?** Nothing will change for a panel having docked = fill, the size is calculated based on it's parent size.

Comment: If you remove the dock from control, the control always will use the last size which is set for it directly. So if you set size for your docked control at run-time, then that size will be used for it if you remove dock, otherwise the serialized size (which is the last manually set size) will be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set the `Size`. Setting `Dock` is enough.

The designer serializes all properties which have a value different than their default value. Since setting `Dock` property changes `Size`, the designer serializes it too.

The serialized size just will be used in future, if you set the `Dock` to `None`. Also setting size of a docked control at run-time doesn't have any effect.

Comment: **Note:** If you remove the dock from control, the control always will use the last size which is set for it *manually*. So if you set size for your docked control at run-time, then that size will be used for it if you remove dock, otherwise the serialized size (which is the last manually set size) will be used.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the designer adding this line?

That is a result of the inner working of the designer of the control. The Visual Studio designer takes every property that is not set to its default value. The default value for `Size` eventually [boils down to the default value of `Control.Size`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,3805), which isn't specified. Hence, it is *always* generated by the designer. See as an example [`TabStop`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,3878) where a default value is specified: only setting it to `false` in the designer will generate code.

Does it have any effect on the visual end result of your `TableLayoutPanel`? No.